# Encode array of Self NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, encoding

I have this CoreData entity with a relationship to itself of one-to-may that I need to encode and decode.
If I don't encode `folders` everything is fine, but when I do so, at runtime the app crashes on the line where I encode the `id` with error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b163ff8)`

```swift
class Folder: NSManagedObject, Codable {

  enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    case id, name, folders, parentFolder
  }

  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(folders as! Set<Folder>, forKey: .folders)
    try container.encode(parentFolder, forKey: .parentFolder)
  }
  
  required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    guard let context = decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey.managedObjectContext] as? NSManagedObjectContext else {
      throw DecoderConfigurationError.missingManagedObjectContext
    }
    
    self.init(context: context)
    
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
    self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.folders = try container.decode(Set<Folder>.self, forKey: .folders) as NSSet
    self.parentFolder = try container.decodeIfPresent(Folder.self, forKey: .parentFolder)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are perhaps the sub-folders faulted? I would use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the encode sub folders line and check the state of the Folder object you are encoding.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The object looks ok, but I see that the encoder keeps encoding first the parent folder then the subfolder in an infinite loop

Comment: First check so that you haven't set a folder to be its own parent to rule that out. One idea here is to only encode the relation in one direction (I would encode folders) and ignore the inverse relationship and then in the decoder set the inverse relationship manually. Although I am not sure if you actually need to do the last part or if Core Data will do it for you the same way it is done in "normal" code. I haven't done anything like this myself but it could be worth trying out.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok like that it works, the only problem now is that it encodes the subfolder both inside the parent subfolders array and by itself. So when I decode the array of general folders, the subfolder is duplicated

Comment: This is perhaps a bit more complicated than i first realized, I assume you can have several levels of folders so that a folder can both be a parent and have a parent folder?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes that's the idea. Parent folder -> [Subfolder] -> Each subfolder can have [Subfolder]. And their are all a single type of object (Folder)

Comment: I just reacted on a thing you wrote earlier, that folders get encoded twice so that makes me wonder what your data source is when encoding, is it a flat array with all folders? I would imagine that you wouldn’t get any duplicates if your data source were all the top level folders (parent = nil) and you only encodes those because then the child folders should only be included once.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just changed the to-many relationship to an array of ids. This way it works fine without any workaround. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing relations to parent folder with the `parent_folder_id` and the children folders with `folder_ids`